# Send method as the parameter to another method (clarification)

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, parameters, optional-parameters

I know this question has been asked many times in many forms, but now I want to clarify a few things.

**2 methods: default method and additional method.** First we perform default method with basic operations. Then, if additional method was passed to the default method as the parameter, perform it too.

```
???void Default_Method(???Additional_Method)
{
     //default logic
     //after default logic, call additional method if its name was specified
     ??? - how to call the specified additional method
}

???void Additional_Method()
{
     //additional logic
}

...
```

**And now the most interesting place**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Default_Method(???Additionl_Method???) //here I need to pass Additional_Method as a parameter
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How to declare the methods properly. I marked places to clarify with **???** mark.

And how to make the additional method be an optional parameter of the default method? Is it enough to pass Null when it is not needed?

**REASON FOR THIS QUESTION**

I didn't find a general instruction on how to do it. All examples are full of individual specifics, people use their own understanding when give names to methods and it is not really clear which one does what in their examples, that's why I decided to create the thread with neutral names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Default_Method(Action additionalMethod = null)
{
    //default logic         
    //after default logic, call additional method if its name was specified

    //This if is needed to avoid NullReferenceException
    if (additionalMethod != null)
        additionalMethod();
}

void Additional_Method()
{
    //additional logic
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Default_Method(Additional_Method);
     //OR
     Default_Method();
     //OR
     Default_Method(null);
     //OR
     Default_Method(() => { /*Do something*/}); 
}
```

In this example I assumed that both methods are defined in the same class as `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO best to use an Action:

```
    void Additional_Method()
    {

    }

    void Default_Method(Action a)
    {
        a.Invoke();
    }
```

in your main code use

```
 Default_Method(Additional_Method);
```